# Nginx list contents of network share via UNC?

Tags: nginx

I've seen a couple other questions that talk about listing contents of a directory by using `autoindex on`.  I'm trying to use this in conjunction with a network share and it is not working.

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   downloads.example.com;
    root          c:/webroot/downloads/;
    location / {
        index     index.html;
    }
    location /drivers/ {
        alias     //10.1.0.20/drivers;
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

I can access `downloads.example.com` and get the static index as expected, but when I try to access `downloads.example.com/drivers/` I get a 500 Internal Server Error.  My Nginx error log shows the following entry:

> 2019/09/20 07:57:10 [crit] 4760#2720: *4 GetFileAttributesEx()
>   "//10.1.0.20/drivers" failed (58: The specified server cannot perform
>   the requested operation), client: 10.1.0.1, server:
>   downloads.example.com, request: "GET /drivers/ HTTP/1.1", host:
>   "downloads.example.com", referrer: "http://downloads.example.com/"

I can access `\\10.1.0.20\drivers` from this machine via File Explorer without issues.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: I intended to post this on SU, but after looking at the nginx tag here with over 37,000 questions maybe this is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by creating a symbolic link instead of using UNC directly from NGinx.

```
mklink -d c:\drivers \\10.1.0.21\drivers
```

Then use `c:\drivers` as the alias in the config.